# [rosbridge_websocket.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rosbridge_server] nor is [rosbridge_server] a launch file name

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, rosdep, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I installed `ros-melodic-desktop-full` with `apt-get` and I am unable to start rosbridge. This is what I see:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ apt list ros-melodic-rosbridge-*
Listing... Done
ros-melodic-rosbridge-library/bionic 0.11.13-1bionic.20210112.182152 amd64
ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs/bionic 0.11.13-1bionic.20201211.203430 amd64
ros-melodic-rosbridge-server/bionic 0.11.13-1bionic.20210112.195018 amd64
ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite/bionic 0.11.13-1bionic.20210112.195104 amd64

vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ rosdep db | grep rosbridge
rosbridge_suite -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite
rosbridge_server -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-server
rosbridge_msgs -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs
rosbridge_library -> ros-melodic-rosbridge-library

vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
RLException: [rosbridge_websocket.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rosbridge_server] nor is [rosbridge_server] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

All other answers I can find that are at all similar all say to `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, but I have no such file. I haven't used catkin, just apt-get. I see no `devel/setup.sh` file anywhere:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ locate ros | grep setup.sh
/opt/ros/melodic/local_setup.sh
/opt/ros/melodic/setup.sh
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/local_setup.sh.in
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.sh.in
```

What may be missing?

EDIT: I now tried to do the following without any luck:

```
$ cd ~/ros_ws
$ catkin_make
... successful output ...
$ source ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash
$ roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
RLException: [rosbridge_websocket.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rosbridge_server] nor is [rosbridge_server] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

This is not easy for ROS newbies. No idea what I'm missing yet, and the documentation hasn't led to any clues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375225/%5Brosbridge_websocket.launch%5D-is-neither-a-launch-file-in-package-%5Brosbridge_server%5D-nor-is-%5Brosbridge_server%5D-a-launch-file-name/) by [trusktr](https://answers.ros.org/users/52857/trusktr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-02**:
`apt list ros-melodic-rosbridge-*` lists available packages, not installed packages (they would be noted as such):

```
Listing... Done
ros-melodic-rosbridge-library/bionic,now 0.11.13-1bionic.20210112.182152 amd64 [installed]
ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs/bionic,now 0.11.13-1bionic.20201211.203430 amd64 [installed,automatic]
ros-melodic-rosbridge-server/bionic,now 0.11.13-1bionic.20210112.195018 amd64 [installed]
ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite/bionic,now 0.11.13-1bionic.20210112.195104 amd64 [installed]
```

You can either check that they say "installed", or you can use the `--installed` flag (`apt list --installed ros-melodic-rosbridge-*`) to only show installed packages that meet your criteria.  The output will be similar.

**Comment by [trusktr](https://answers.ros.org/users/52857/trusktr/) on 2021-04-02**:
That was it. I naively thought "desktop-full" meant it came with everything. I also didn't realize I needed the `--install` param to `apt list`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the output of `rospack find rosbridge_server`? If it's not a directory location, then either the package  is missing or not visible.

`ros-melodic-desktop-full` doesn't have RosBridge, you'd have to install it separately using `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite` (check out [RosBridge tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite/Tutorials/RunningRosbridge)).

After installing RosBridge, re-source ROS and then try launching `rosbridge_websocket.launch`.

---

Originally posted by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) with karma: 228 on 2021-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trusktr](https://answers.ros.org/users/52857/trusktr/) on 2021-04-02**:
That was it. I for some reason thought "ros-melodic-desktop-full" implied it came with "everything".

After installing `ros-melodic-rosbridge-*`, then `roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch` worked.

Thanks!